# Open URL with chromium then close after time

Tags: raspbian, chromium

I'm trying to write a bash script on Raspbian that will open a video URL in fullscreen, wait 2 minutes, then close the window

```
#!/bin/bash
chromium-browser <url> --start-fullscreen
sleep 120
pkill chromium
```

However, the code won't kill the chromium window.

Answer (score 3):

Another [simple method](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html)

```
timeout 120 chromium-browser https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem:

```
chromium-browser <url> --start-fullscreen
```

That command will run forever until the user closes the window.
Same reason why running this command in the terminal will not return you to the prompt (`pi@raspberrypi:~ $`) until the command is finished. In other words, the script *never reaches* the further lines in your script, but is stuck there.

To start the command, then move on, just add a `&` to the chromium-browser command. Like this:

```
chromium-browser <url> --start-fullscreen &
```

Bash will start this command, then go to to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pkill` with the process ID, which can be found like this

```
pid = pidof <process name>
```

The process ID has been assigned to the variable `pid`. Then just use `pkill` with that variable

```
pkill pid
```

Comment: will the process ID be changed with each new instance of chromium being opened?

Comment: Most likely, yes.